# The API developer key is invalid when viewing file in google picker

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-picker

I want to view all files in google picker for that i am following this link:

> https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

but it returns The API developer key is invalid.

My code is as follows but that key is working properly in other projects:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Picker Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
    // Replace with your own Browser API key, or your own key.
    var developerKey = 'AXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXM';

    // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console. Replace with your own Client ID.
    var clientId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com"

    // Replace with your own App ID. (Its the first number in your Client ID)
    var appId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";

    // Scope to use to access user's Drive items.
    var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

    var pickerApiLoaded = false;
    var oauthToken;

    // Use the Google API Loader script to load the google.picker script.
    function loadPicker() {
      gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
      gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
    }

    function onAuthApiLoad() {
      window.gapi.auth.authorize(
          {
            'client_id': clientId,
            'scope': scope,
            'immediate': false
          },
          handleAuthResult);
    }

    function onPickerApiLoad() {
      pickerApiLoaded = true;
      createPicker();
    }

    function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
      if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
        oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
        createPicker();
      }
    }

    // Create and render a Picker object for searching images.
    function createPicker() {
      if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
        var view = new google.picker.View(google.picker.ViewId.DOCS);
        view.setMimeTypes("image/png,image/jpeg,image/jpg");
        var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder()
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.NAV_HIDDEN)
            .enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED)
            .setAppId(appId)
            .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
            .addView(view)
            .addView(new google.picker.DocsUploadView())
            .setDeveloperKey(developerKey)
            .setCallback(pickerCallback)
            .build();
         picker.setVisible(true);
      }
    }

    // A simple callback implementation.
    function pickerCallback(data) {
      if (data.action == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
        var fileId = data.docs[0].id;
        alert('The user selected: ' + fileId);
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=loadPicker"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What types of credentials did you add to google developers console?

Comment: I seem to be having the same issue.  Credentials I have are an API Key where Type = "Browser".  That is what I am passing into setDeveloperKey.
I also have an OAuth 2.0 client ID where Type = "Web application".  I am passing the clientId.split('-')[0] to setAppId.  setOAuthToken is being passed a valid auth token that I am able to use to retrieve files from the Drive API.
picker.setVisible(true) results in a popup that just says "The API developer key is invalid."  If I remove the call to setDeveloperKey then the picker works.

Answer (score 6):

It seems you did not enabled "google picker API" in google console